# HTML elements in Angular bindings expression

Tags: html, angularjs

Is that possible to insert HTML elements in an Angular expression ?
Let's take a few example.

I would like to do something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
        <td>{{employee.firstname ? employee.firstname : '<p style="color:red">No name</p>'}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.job}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In our controller, we have:

```
$scope.employees = [{firstname:'Bob', job:'Developer'},
                    {firstname:'Paul', job:'Manager'},
                    {job:'Developer'}]
```

We show all employees (name/job), when we don't have the name of the person, we show `No name`.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) in this case

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <td ng-if="employee.firstname">{{employee.firstname}}</td>
    <td ng-if="!employee.firstname"><p style="color:red">No name</p></td>
    <td>{{employee.job}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Maybe this could be better ?

`<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
        <td ng-if="employee.firstname">{{employee.firstname}}
          <p style="color:red" ng-if="!employee.firstname">No name</p>
        </td>
        <td>{{employee.job}}</td>
</tr>`

Comment: @Mistalis: IMHO ng-if in this scenario is more apt as you need to check the condition only once. So if firstname is not there then DOM elements wont increase

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow), it will show the paragraph if employee.firstname is null.

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <td>{{employee.firstname }}<p ng-show="!employee.firstname" style="color:red">No name</p></td>
    <td>{{employee.job}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-bind` in this case

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees" ng-bind="functionName(argument);"></tr>
```

And in the controller, you can put your logic inside the `functionName()` function.

```
$scope.functionName(){
  //Your logic goes here
}
```

Based on your condition, return the relevant `html`